# Ionic 2 (Angular) GroupBy Pipe

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic2

I'm having a trouble grouping my objects, I'm trying to use the ngx-group-by pipe but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Assuming the data structure is :
Every company has it products (which contains sub products), and it prices;
For example our company is XXX and it sales cars and motorcycles: 

Products : TwoWheels , FourWheels

SubProducts : Bike,Motorcycle (TwoWheels) , Cars (FourWheels)

I'm trying to display the price for every SubProduct and group it by the ProductId
Here's my Json:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "test",
  "lastName": "tast",
  "displayName": "myname",
  "profilePic": "none",
  "location": "mylocation",
  "pricingList": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "userId": 1,
      "ProductId": 1,
      "subProductId": 1,
      "price": 50,
      "subProduct": {
        "id": 1,
        "ProductId": 1,
        "name": "MotorCycle",
        "treatment": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "TwoWheels"
        }
      },
      "Product": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "TwoWheels"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "userId": 1,
      "ProductId": 1,
      "subTreatmentId": 7,
      "price": 50,
      "subProduct": {
        "id": 7,
        "ProductId": 1,
        "name": "bike",
        "Product": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "TwoWheels"
        }
      },
      "Product": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "TwoWheels"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "userId": 1,
      "ProductId": 2,
      "subTreatmentId": 8,
      "price": 30,
      "subProduct": {
        "id": 8,
        "treatmentId": 2,
        "name": "Car",
        "Product": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "FourWheels"
        }
      },
      "Product": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "FourWheels"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's my Ionic 2/Angular html:

```html
<div *ngFor="let p of User.pricingList | groupBy:p.ProductId">
    <div class="ProductTitle">{{p.Product.name}}</div>
    <div>
        <div class="myClass">Name</div>
        <div class="myClass">Price</div>
    </div>
    <div style="myClass2">
        <div class="myClass">{{p.subProduct.name}}</div>
        <div class="myClass">{{p.price}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[GroupByPipe implementation](https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes/blob/master/src/app/pipes/array/group-by.ts)

Comment: You said you tried the `ngx-group-by` pipe however is isn't shown in the code you've posted? Could you create a plunker [here's a template to get started](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue)

Comment: I didn't include the group-by pipe indeed, I assumed it's common and known, I will edit and add the pipe code, creating the plunkr is bit complicated since my app is kinda messy

Comment: @0mpurdy I added the pipe, could you take a look please?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - I didn't mean the actual pipe itself I meant where you had used it :)

Comment: @0mpurdy Oh that's the problem, I had no success using it, in my *ngFor statement I added : " | groupBy: 'p.productId'  "  but it didn't work

Comment: That would be useful if you added it to the question, you should probably replace the GroupBy code with this link: https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes/blob/master/src/app/pipes/array/group-by.ts

Comment: @0mpurdy but this is exactly what I have! I did add the pipe I have (which is the one you suggested)

Comment: I'll make an edit to show you what I mean

Comment: your code in the comment has errors in it - it should be `| groupBy:p.ProductId` is that what you had when you tried it?

Comment: @0mpurdy I understand and accepted your edit, that's exactly what I did but it's not working :/

Comment: @0mpurdy yes, I did just as you said and tried lots of different variations but none seems to work

Comment: I cannot find a plunker for ngx-pipes so I am testing it now locally it may take a few minutes

Comment: @0mpurdy Thanks a lot! (I'm not sure if it's allowed in here, but skype is an option to farther help?)

Comment: No, it is not I'm afraid - this is a question and answer site nothing more

Comment: No problem! I'll wait

Comment: Ok I can't get `ngx-pipes` to even install so I won't be able to help you any further sorry! Hopefully someone else is more familiar with it

Comment: @0mpurdy hopefully.. thanks for the attention anyway